# How to animate Box size to 'fillMaxSize' and then back to 0 using animateContentSize?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-jetpack-compose

Here's the problem:

[image]

In the above pic, I want to animate the blue box size on click. When I click on that box, I want to animate the size of that to max size (fillMaxSize), and then back to 0 when clicked.

The animation from 0 size to fillMaxSize is happening. But animation from max size to 0 size is not happening.

Here's the code snippet:

```
var tabSelected by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .clip(shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp))
                    .animateContentSize()
                    .fillMaxSize(if(tabSelected) 1f else 0f)
                    .background(Color.Blue)
                    .clickable(
                        interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() },
                        indication = null
                    ) {
                        tabSelected = !tabSelected
                    }
            )
```

EDIT: Here's the complete code:

```
package com.example.customtabexample

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.animation.animateContentSize
import androidx.compose.foundation.background
import androidx.compose.foundation.border
import androidx.compose.foundation.clickable
import androidx.compose.foundation.interaction.MutableInteractionSource
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Box
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.IntrinsicSize
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Row
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Spacer
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.aspectRatio
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxHeight
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxWidth
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.height
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.size
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.width
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.wrapContentHeight
import androidx.compose.foundation.shape.RoundedCornerShape
import androidx.compose.material3.Button
import androidx.compose.material3.ButtonDefaults
import androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material3.Surface
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.runtime.setValue
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.draw.clip
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.text.style.TextAlign
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import com.example.customtabexample.ui.theme.CustomTabExampleTheme

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            TopBar()
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun TopBar(){
    var tabSelected by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .height(IntrinsicSize.Min)
            .border(1.dp, Color.Black)
            .padding(start = 8.dp, end = 8.dp, top = 7.dp, bottom = 7.dp)
    ){
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .clip(shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp))
                .fillMaxHeight()
                .background(Color.LightGray)
                .padding(start = 25.dp, end = 25.dp, top = 12.dp, bottom = 12.dp),
            contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
        ){
            Text(
                text = "i"
            )
        }
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(8.dp))
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .weight(0.25f)
                .fillMaxHeight(),
            contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
        ){
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .clip(shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp))
                    .animateContentSize()
                    .fillMaxSize(if(tabSelected) 1f else 0f)
                    .background(Color.Blue)
                    .clickable(
                        interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() },
                        indication = null
                    ) {
                        tabSelected = !tabSelected
                    }
            )
            Text(text = "1")
        }
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(8.dp))
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .weight(0.25f)
                .fillMaxHeight(),
            contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
        ){
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .clip(shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp))
                    .background(Color.Gray)
                    .fillMaxSize()
            )
            Text(text = "2")
        }
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(8.dp))
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .weight(0.25f)
                .fillMaxHeight(),
            contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
        ){
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .clip(shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp))
                    .background(Color.Gray)
                    .fillMaxSize()
            )
            Text(text = "3")
        }
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(8.dp))
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .clip(shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp))
                .fillMaxHeight()
                .background(Color.LightGray)
                .padding(start = 25.dp, end = 25.dp, top = 12.dp, bottom = 12.dp),
            contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
        ){
            Text(
                text = "s"
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add your full code?

Comment: @404NotFound I've added the complete code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ordering of where animateContentSize is placed in your modifier chain matters. You need to put color before animateContentSize()

```
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .clip(shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp))
                    .background(Color.Blue)
                    .animateContentSize()
                    .fillMaxSize(if(tabSelected) 1f else 0f)
                    .clickable(
                        interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() },
                        indication = null
                    ) {
                        tabSelected = !tabSelected
                    }
            )
```

You can check more info [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/animation/composables-modifiers#animation-modifiers)